# Generate signed apk/app bundle option not working

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, apk

I just purchased an app and i am trying to edit it and then publish it to the google play store. the app doesnt have a build.gradle files and when i open it in android studio i only get 3 options for the build, make a module, analyze apk and deploy module to app engine. i do not have the option to generate a signed android app bundle to publish to google play which is what i am trying to do.

ive tried adding a configuration and chose android app but there is a red X near the configuration symbol. the app also does not have any facets.

i am not recieving an error message the generate app bundle isnt showing.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem right now.